# how to use headers only in the chapters and not in List of tables, List of Figures, Bibliography. e.t.c

Tags: header-footer

Im writing with 
`\documentclass[12pt, twoside, openrany]{report}`

My problem is that when i use

```
\pagestyle{headings}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\fancyfoot{}                            % Delete current footer settings
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark}
\fancyfoot[LO,LE]{\small\thepage}
\fancyfoot[RO,RE]{\small \textgreek{'Aggelos Armen'atzoglou}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%\setlength{\headsep}{0.2in}
```

i get the headers also to the list of contents, list of tables, list of figures and bibliography, which i don't want.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Jusr before these, add the line:  `\pagestyle{plain}`.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `\pagestyle{plain}` before these, and, as egreg pointed, `\pagestyle{fancy}` at the point you want the standard headers to start.

Comment: And `\pagestyle{fancy}` at the point where the standard headers should start.

Comment: @egreg: You're right. That goes without saying, but probably goes better saying it. I'll add it.